# Comparing 2 XML files in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, blob

I am importing XML files into a SQL table as SINGLE_BLOBS:

```
INSERT INTO #XMLSource(XmlData)
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK C:\TEXT.XML, SINGLE_BLOB) AS ImportSource
```

does anyone know of a way to compare either the XML files prior to import or the SINGLE_BLOBS after import?  I just need to see if the file has been changed.

Comment: You want to compare the XML files using solely SQL?

Comment: compare hash code for both the string.

Comment: @pringi Yes - from SQL if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Importing as `SINGLE_BLOB` wil result in a `varbinary(max)`, you can simply use the `=` operator. What is the problem?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Hash code might be my answer, I am trying to keep a log of imported files and make sure I don't import the same file twice.  So would no longer keep the original SINGLE_BLOBs.

Comment: Can't you put a `unique` constraint on your table?

Comment: @HoneyBadger  It is a temp table, so will not have access to the old import files, but could store the hash codes somewhere...